# Fake Function Framework - How Do I Fake Functions Marked __declspec(dllimport) And Avoid Inconsistend DLL Linkage?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for a function that calls a third party API. I'd like to create fakes for the functions from the API because, for the tests, I don't want to actually call the API. Because the API calls are coming from a DLL the API header correctly marks them as `__declspec(dllimport)`.

When using Fake Function Framework to create fakes to make sure that the correct functions are called its macros create real calls for them. I don't see a way (nor do I think it'd be possible) to make these generated functions dllimport since they're not actually being imported.

I have also tried defining an "under test" macro that will cause the API header to not be included. This, however, doesn't work if I want to maintain the stock definitions of the custom data types (structs & enums) that come from that header. I could redefine these types in my tests but I'm hesitant to bloat the test code with these if I don't have to.

Are there other ideas for what I can try  in such a situation?

Comment: So your tests won't actually be calling the real functions, but just fake ones, so they'll be testing the behaviour of the fake functions rather than the real ones? Sounds like a really useful test (insert sarcasm here).

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is actually quite common ;) Read about mocking if you're interested.

Comment: @qz I *know* it is common. That doesn't make it seem any less stupid to me. Why would you want to test fake code that you never run in production, rather than testing the real code that you actually deploy?

Comment: Sometimes testing on the real production endpoints is not possible or highly undesirable.

Comment: @qz but are your tests then really testing anything interesting? If they don't test the code you actually push into production at customers then what's the point?

Comment: I think you've confused me with the question author.

Comment: Why not just #ifdef  UNITTEST \ #include "fakes.h" \ #else \ #include "real.h" \ #endif

Comment: @JesperJuhl - To answer your questions about whether it's worthwhile, yes it is. The APIs I'm calling control some hardware. I want to test my logic that tells the hardware what to do without actually calling the API that operates the hardware.

Hans Passant - That is what I meant in the question about setting up a macro that causes the API header to not be included and looking for a way other than creating a separate header that replicates most of the API header.

Comment: Is the API that big then?